# Class 2D vector problems

Tags: c++

Alrighty. I have a class Sphere. I am trying to initialize the coordinates for a UVSphere with a given number of subdivisions. The class has a 2D vector verts that looks like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<Angel::vec3>> verts;
```

Where vec3 is essentially a struct of three floats

I have two functions

```
void setupSphere();
void setupRaw();
```

Whose implementation looks like this:

```
void Sphere::setupSphere()
{
float pi = std::atan(1.0f) * 4.0f;
float subdivAngle = 2 * pi / numSubdivide;

std::vector<Angel::vec3> yVectors;
yVectors.reserve(numSubdivide);
for (int i = 0; i < numSubdivide; i ++)
{
    float curAngle = subdivAngle * i;
    yVectors.push_back(Angel::vec3(std::cos(curAngle), 0.0, -std::sin(curAngle)));
}

int zNumSubdivide = numSubdivide + 4;
float zAngle = 2 * pi / zNumSubdivide;

for (int i = 1; i < zNumSubdivide / 2; i ++)
{
    float curAngle = pi / 2 - zAngle * i;
    float yCoord = std::sin(curAngle);
    float xzScale = std::cos(curAngle);
    std::vector<Angel::vec3> curVector;

    for (int j = 0; j < numSubdivide; j ++)
    {
        Angel::vec3 newPoint = yVectors[j] * xzScale;
        newPoint.y = yCoord;
        curVector.push_back(newPoint);
    }
    verts.push_back(curVector);
}

std::cout << "Size = " << verts.size() << std::endl;
setupRaw();
//setupTexture();
}

void Sphere::setupRaw()
{
std::cout << "TESTING" << std::endl;
std::cout << "Size = " << verts.size();
}
```

When I look at the contents of verts at the end of setupSphere() then it looks great, but in setupRaw() it crashes when I try to print the size of verts. What is going on here?

Comment: Curious: How did you find out that it is the `setupRaw()` that crashes, not before?

Comment: Debugger says, Name : verts
 Details:{<std::_Vector_base<std::vector<Angel::vec3, std::allocator<Angel::vec3> >, std::allocator<std::vector<Angel::vec3, std::allocator<Angel::vec3> > > >> = {_M_impl = {<std::allocator<std::vector<Angel::vec3, std::allocator<Angel::vec3> > >> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::vector<Angel::vec3, std::allocator<Angel::vec3> > >> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_start = 0xa34ea0, _M_finish = 0xa34edc, _M_end_of_storage = 0xa34f00}}, <No data fields>}
 Default:{...}
 Decimal:{...}
 Hex:{...}
 Binary:{...}
 Octal:{...}

Comment: And as for Arun I know because it prints "TESTING" then crashes before printing anything else.

Comment: Never mind the debugger, what is the console error message you get when it crashes? Segmentation fault?

Comment: Hmm... thanks! Can you try commenting out portions of your code and see what is the minimum code that leads to crash?

Comment: Also, *"vec3 is **essentially** a struct of three floats"*. Essentially, close enough, are all synonymous with the word "not" as far as I'm concerned. Clearly its not just a POD-type; you're firing the constructor in your insert. Include the full declaration of that structure at the top of your source listing. Not some "close enough" copy; the **real** declaration. Further, running this under GDB or WinDbg would probably tell you instantly where the problem lies.

Comment: Well it seems my comment was deleted. Thanks to Arun's comment I was able to find that my problem wasn't with the verts.size() function as I had thought but there was a problem later in setupRaw. Why then didn't it print the size of my vector before crashing?